# grails.server.port has no effect anymore in BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: grails

`grails.server.port` has no effect anymore in `BuildConfig.groovy`
should always pass

`-Dserver.port=XXXX`

Grails version 2.1.1

Comment: Where do you get the wrong path? From the root url or when controller redirect to other actions?

Comment: during startup it still binds to 8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is

```
grails.server.port.http = xxxx
```

not

```
grails.server.port = xxxx
```

But there are something further to be checked:

1. If you deploy the app upon Unix platforms, all ports below 1024 can only be accessed by root user. Otherwise you will get an error like `Error Server failed to start for port 80: Permission denied`
2. The redirect() method uses the grails.serverURL config setting to generate the redirect URL. You may need to remove the setting, particularly from the development and test environments.